# Connect an iPhone to OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, iphone

Is there a way to connect an iPhone to our company OpenVPN server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenVPN.net finally released an official client for iOS:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981

Comment: Wow we had to wait almost 4 years since I asked this question to get an answer...

Answer (score 9):

I have it working on a jailbroken iPhone 3.x. Detailed instructions can be found at http://chandraonline.net/blog/?p=22.

Comment: @That's great, thanks. Now if only it worked on non-jailbroken iPhones...

Answer (score 7):

As of the latest iPhone OS release (3.0) this is not possible. I am unsure if someone could create an 'all in one' client that connects to OpenVPN and then allows you to browse the web from within the same app.

But certainly any app that connected to OpenVPN could not then be put into the background allowing you to use the built in Mobile Safari or Mobile Mail over the VPN.

Comment: Your answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 7):

I've looked into this and unfortunately it's not possible, and it's unlikely to happen any time soon. While it's relatively easy to write the software for the iPhone, the problem is that it needs a tap/tun interface to create the OpenVPN tunnel, which is not present in the iPhone currently.

Comment: Your answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a solution for [jailbroken iPhones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) here:
http://code.gerade.org/tunemu/

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! Maybe something could be made by developing an app which includes this code and an integrated web view. So we could at least browse the web servers on the VPN. Of course it would be way better to have this system-wide.